Ubuntu 22.04 audio not work with ALC892
I've MB TOMAHAWK B350 with Chipset ALC892, audio work fine random but, sometimes is mute or crackling.
On goolgle the are many configuration about this ALC892 but never resolve the problem.<
I spent more days to search solution
$ aplay -l
**** Lista di PLAYBACK dispositivi hardware ****
scheda 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Sottoperiferiche: 0/1
Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], dispositivo 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], dispositivo 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], dispositivo 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], dispositivo 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
Sottoperiferiche: 0/1
Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0

Could you help me please ?
Thanks

The problem should be when audio doesn't work,
I run journalctl -b  |grep -i Failed  and find
apr 12 09:12:03 MS-7A34 (udev-worker)[695]: controlC1: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore 1' failed with exit code 99.
apr 12 09:12:05 MS-7A34 alsactl[1160]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #5 (No such file or directory)
apr 12 09:12:05 MS-7A34 alsactl[1160]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #6 (No such file or directory)

I can't find a solution

Update ......
The problem still again using step before, now I've removed card using UDEV
lspci -nn -s 28:00
28:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, <br/>Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 31 [Radeon RX 7900 XT/7900 XTX] [1002:744c] (rev ce)

add file
/etc/udev/rules.d/10-remove-amd-audio.rules
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="0000:28:00.1", SUBSYSTEM=="pci", RUN="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:28:00.1/remove"

reboot

there is only audio on board
lspci |grep -i audio
2a:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller

at the moment works fine

Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - From Review

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
